# How to show background image of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

In my winform project I have tabbing in my form and in each tab I have datagridview ,I know how to cell image for cells of datagridview but how can I set `image` as `background of datagridview` , I searched for it but didn't found any proper solution ,Please if anyone can direct me to right way

Comment: Check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/628f8b29-1192-4c67-bae9-91547dd37039/assign-background-image-to-datagridview?forum=winforms

Comment: @AccessDenied I tried this before but above link is not helpful

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17648/Set-Image-as-Background-for-DataGridView check this